# Only null value to send to the database when the form is click

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have use a jquery mobile form on php using Dreamweaver cs5.5.. a form is use in order to include the post function.. my server is mysql in zymichost.com.. it happen that everytime i run the form.. null value is send to my database.. even when value is inserted into the textfield and press submit.. still null value is send to the database.. may i know wat the problem is? your cooperation is appreciated...  i have jz updated the code with remove the space between $_POST and ['name'] and change the $_POST ['password'] to $_POST['pass']..
it happen to be the same result as before..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Cloud</title>

<?php

$un = $_POST['name'];
$em = $_POST['email'];
$pw = $_POST['pass'];

//$un = 'abc';
//$pw = 'abc';

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "mycloud_zymichost_register";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass";

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn );

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
//$query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pw'";
$query = "INSERT INTO Register (name,email,pass) VALUES ('$un','$em','$pw')";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());  

// if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)  

//echo 1;   
//else  
//echo 0; 
 echo print_r($_POST, true);
}

?>




<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Register

<form action="index.php" method="post" name="form">

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="pass">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value=""  />
</div>
<a href="index.php" data-role="button" name="submit">Submit</a>
</form>


</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Footer</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have use a jquery mobile form on php using Dreamweaver cs5.5.. a form is use in order to include the post function.. my server is mysql in zymichost.com.. it happen that everytime i run the form.. null value is send to my database.. even when value is inserted into the textfield and press submit.. still null value is send to the database.. may i know wat the problem is? your cooperation is appreciated... i have jz updated the code with remove the space between $_POST and ['name'] and change the $_POST ['password'] to $_POST['pass']..
it happen to be the same result as before..

Comment: I wouldn't suggest including username/password info in your question like that

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes. Enjoy getting your server pwn3d. Have you checked a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's being sent to your server? The PHP code could be otheriwse fine and your client-side HTML form is broken.

Comment: @MarcB Why not suggest something useful regarding SQL injection?

Comment: @Madbreaks, can teach me how to write a mysql_real_escape_string?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get null value because you have used `<a>` tag for submit button, it will not submit the page but it will redirect you on page specified.

Instead of it(`<a>`) try to use button code:

```
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" value="submit-value">Submit</button>
```

also view this link:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

It will gives you example of ajax form submit and non-ajax form submit

One other thing I want to suggest you that, use latest stable version of jquerymobile and its supported jquery.js file

Hope this will help you

Comment: glad that my suggestions help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue:

```
$pw = $_POST ['password'];
```

...and...

```
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value=""  />
```

Note that the name of your input is **pass**, but you're using $_POST['**password**']

Comment: Please update your question with the new code showing what you've tried.

Comment: Try putting something like this at the top of your script: `echo print_r($_POST, true);` ...to see if the server is getting the values from your form.

Comment: i get this output Unable to verify user because : Query was empty

Comment: i hav jz update the code with if (isset($_POST['submit'])){} as well as @Madbreaks code ..

Comment: You don't have an input named "submit", that if statement will always evaluate to false. Try `if(!empty($_POST)){...}` or similar instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the value="" field from the password input, and also, change the name="password" to name="pass"

The password field should look like this:

```
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
```